# How to pass value by reference in this case?

Tags: java

I need a way to check if a boolean value of another object is true, and only in that case should do something.

So, I have 2 classes:

```
public class A{
   private boolean test = false;
   ...
   ...

   public boolean returnTest(){ return test; }
}




public class B{
   private boolean abcd;

   public B(A myA){
      this.abcd = myA.returnTest();
   }

   public void test(){
      while(!abcd){
         // wait
      }
      // do something

   }

}
```

The problem is that it remain in the while loop forever even if the **test** value of the object **A** become **true**. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, pass instance to function test() is better, invoke `test()` with passing instance of `A`. Everytime an new instance of `A` is created or an existing instance has updated its attributes, pass it to `test()`

```
   public void test(A a){
        while(!a.returnTest()){
            // wait            
        }
    }
```

Comment: `test` needs to be `volatile` as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real alternative to changing `test()` to do `while (!myA.returnTest())`.  If you store a result in a variable it will stay permanently.  (*Properties* of objects, or method calls, can reflect changes elsewhere, but variables themselves cannot.)

Comment: Should I pass the entire object A ?

Comment: Yes, basically.

Answer (score 0):

Booleans are immutable so you cannot make a copy of a reference to them.

Instead, try:

```
public class B{
   private A a;

   public B(A myA){
      this.a= myA();
   }

   public void test(){
      while(!myA.returnTest()){
         // wait
      }
      // do something

   }
}
```

Comment: objects are stored by reference ?

Comment: Yup objects are stored by reference. `boolean` is a primitive, not an object. If you use `Boolean` it also won't work since that is immutable as well. You could use [`AtomicBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) though.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do so, one option is to use a [`java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html), which is mutable type. You can retrieve and update values using `get()` and `set(boolean)` respectively. This can also be a good option if thread-safety can potentially be a concern in your application.

Otherwise you have to store a reference to the `A` instance and use the flag inside it instead of checking a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can use a method reference.

```
public class A{
   private boolean test = false;
   ...
   ...

   public boolean returnTest(){ return test; }
}




public class B{
   private BooleanSupplier abcd;

   public B(A myA){
      this.abcd = myA::returnTest; // a reference to this method.
   }

   public void test(){
      while(!abcd.getAsBoolean()) { // calls the method each time.
         // wait
      }
      // do something

   }

}
```